# Despite of being use WebP format for images, "serve image in next generation" issue still come

Tags: image, blogger, webp, image-optimization, next-generation-plugin

In my website (on blogger) I used all images in WebP format still Google page speed insight give the error of server image in next generation... Why this occurs any one help...
[image]
One more thing that i noticed is I had uploaded (for ex.) Image of 30 KB and on Google page speed insight it showing the size is 40 + KB I can't able to understand why this happening.... And same occur with each images in my website

**Ps: My all images are under 50 KB but the size it showing is disastrous..**.

Comment: can you provide an url ?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to try other test sites similar to Google tool, such as GTmetrix, Pingdom, StresStimulus, DareBoost or KeyCDN Site Speed Test.

Don't take test results done in Google PageSpeed Insights too seriously, as they are not accurate.